# Unable to use AWK redirection

Tags: awk, command-line, io-redirection

I want to use the [AWK redirection feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) and what I've done so far is this :

```
$ vmstat 1 | awk ' { print $2 > "outfile" } '
```

*Actually the commands before `awk` are a lot more complicated , but it's a simplified demonstration.

If I run the above command without redirection , I would get the desired result in the stdout. But after redirecting it to `outfile` , it's still empty :

```
$ cat outfile
$
```

What's wrong with that ?

TIA.

Comment: Does giving awk the `-W interactive` option help?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick "awk: option `-W interactive' unrecognized, ignored" . I used it as follows : "vmstat 1 | awk -W interactive ' { print $1 } ' "  . Btw I use awk 4.1.4.

Comment: OK. There are a few different implementations of awk out there, and `-W interactive` is supported by `mawk`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Mine is Gawk . But I  have Mawk too . Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`awk` buffers its output. If your awk implementation provides it (as gawk, mawk<sup>1</sup>, nawk, and BSD awk do), use `fflush()`.

> ```
>   fflush([file])        Flush any buffers associated with the open output file 
>                         or pipe file.  If file is missing or if it is  the null 
>                         string,  then  flush  all open output files and pipes.
> ```

So, write it this way:

```
vmstat 1 | awk '{print $2 > "outfile"; fflush()}'
```

[The GNU awk manual I/O section](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html) on `fflush` is a worth reading. There you will also find that [`fflush` has been accepted to the next POSIX standard](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=634).

---

As an extra, notice that you can give the number of samples that `vmstat` should output. So, if you want only `5` samples (for example), you can wait the 5 seconds until the command terminates and then the file will contain the output:

```
vmstat 1 5 | awk '{print $2 > "outfile"}'
```

---

<sup>1</sup>With mawk the syntax is a bit different: `mawk -W interactive '{print $2 > "outfile"; fflush("")}'`.

Comment: There appears to be a slight difference in usage between `gawk`, which says of ``fflush([file])`` *If file is missing or  if  it is  the  null  string, then flush all open output files and pipes.* and `mawk` which says *`fflush` without an argument flushes stdout.  `fflush` with an empty  argument ("") flushes all open output.*. Regardless, I can't seem to get the above to work with mawk v.1.3.3 nor v.1.3.4 , either with `fflush()` or `fflush("")`. Any idea why?

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for catching that. I reproduced that behavior but no, I do not know what is going on there with mawk. I updated the answer to include that. I will contact Thomas Dickey to see if he could dispel our confusion.

Comment: For mawk, add the `-W interactive` option.

Comment: @steeldriver `mawk` also has that peculiar behaviour in that it waits until it has accumulated a buffer-full of input before considering processing it, disabled  with `-W interactive`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks - that was indeed what I was missing

Answer (score 5):

The problem is buffering, it can be disabled.

```
vmstat 1 | stdbuf -o0 awk '{print $2}' >> out
```

- `-o` output stream
- `0` stream will be unbuffered

or you can call `vmstat` in `while` loop with `sleep 1`

```
while true; do 
     vmstat | awk '{print $2}' >> output.file
     sleep 1
done
```

Comment: You should also be able to place the piping to `awk` _after_ the loop: `... done | awk ... >out`.